# If $|G_{{\rm ab}}|$ and $|Z(G)|$ are coprime for finite $G$, then $G$ has a unique Remak decomposition.

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, direct-product

This is **Exercise 3.3.7** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)."* According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7CG_%7B%7B%5Crm%20ab%7D%7D%7C%24%2C%20%24%7CZ(G)%7C%24%20coprime%2C%20remak&p=10), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

On page 28, *ibid.*,

> A *right operator group* is a triple $(G, \Omega, \alpha)$ consisting of a group $G$, a set $\Omega$ called the *operator domain* and a function $\alpha:G\times \Omega\to G$ such that $g\mapsto (g,\omega)\alpha$ is an endomorphism of $G$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. We shall write $g^\omega$ for $(g,\omega)\alpha$ and speak of the *$\Omega$-group* if the function $\alpha$ is understood.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If $G$ is an $\Omega$-group, an *$\Omega$-subgroup* of $G$ is a subgroup $H$ which is *$\Omega$-admissible*, that is, such that $h^\omega\in H$ whenever $h\in H$ and $\omega\in\Omega$.

On page 60, *ibid.*,

> [Consider] a partially ordered set $\Lambda$ with partial order $\le$. We say that $\Lambda$ satisfies the *maximal condition* of each nonempty subset $\Lambda_0$ contains at least one *maximal element*.

Analogously, the *minimal condition* is defined.

On page 80, *ibid.*,

> Let $G$ be a group with operator domain $\Omega$. An $\Omega$-subgroup $H$ is called an *$\Omega$-direct factor* of $G$ If there exists an $\Omega$-subgroup $K$ such that $G=H\times K$; then $K$ is called an *$\Omega$-direct complement* of $H$ in $G$. If there are no proper nontrivial $\Omega$-direct factors of $G$, then $G$ is said to be *$\Omega$-indecomposable* [. . .].

On page 81, *ibid*

> [The maximal and minimal conditions on $\Omega$-direct factors being equivalent guarantees that an] $\Omega$-group may be expressed as a direct product of finitely many nontrivial $\Omega$-indecomposable subgroups: such a direct decomposition is called a *Remak decomposition*.
>
> **Theorem (Remak):** If an $\Omega$-group $G$ has the minimal condition on $\Omega$-direct factors, it has a Remak decomposition.

On page 92, *ibid.*, there are the following two exercises:

> **Exercise 3.3.4:** Prove that the central automorphisms of a group $G$ form a subgroup ${\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}\ G$ of ${\rm Aut}\ G$.

*Proof:* Simply apply the one-step subgroup test.$\square$

> **Exercise 3.3.5 (J.E. Adney and Ti Yen):** Let $G$ be a finite group which has no nontrivial abelian direct factors. Prove that $\lvert{\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}\ G\rvert =\lvert {\rm Hom}(G_{{\rm ab}}, Z(G))\rvert$. Deduce that if $G$ has no nontrivial central automorphisms, then $Z(G)\le G'$.

*Proof:* This follows rather easily from the hint: "If $\alpha\in {\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}\ G$, define $\theta_\alpha\in{\rm Hom}(G_{{\rm ab}}, Z(G))$ by $(gG')^{\theta_\alpha}=g^{-1}g^\alpha$. Show that $\alpha\mapsto \theta_\alpha$ is a bijection."$\square$

### The Question:

> If $G$ is a finite group and $|G_{{\rm ab}}|$ and $|Z(G)|$ are coprime, prove that $G$ has a unique Remak decomposition.

### Thoughts:

I think that **Exercise 3.3.5** (along with, say, Lagrange's theorem) is required but I'm not sure how to implement it here.

Of course, there is, on page 83, the

> **Theorem (Krull, Remak, Schmidt):** Let $G$ be an $\Omega$-group satisfying the maximal and minimal conditions on normal $\Omega$-subgroups. If
>
> $$G=H_1\times \dots\times H_r=K_1\times \dots \times K_s$$
>
> are two Remak decompositions of $G$, then $r=s$ and there is a central $\Omega$-automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ such that, after suitable relabelling of the $K_j$s if necessary, $H_i^\alpha=K_i$ and $$G=K_1\times \dots \times K_k\times H_{k+1}\times \dots \times H_r$$ for $k=1,\dots, r$.

It is noted, though, shortly after the proof, that this theorem does not guarantee the uniqueness of the Remak decomposition.

There is a couple of other, rather technical theorems on uniqueness of Remak decompositions in the ensuing pages but I shall not share them here, since this is too long a post already and I don't see how to apply them.

This is not an exercise I think I can do myself any time soon.

I am reminded of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, say, or the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups; so these are similar problems I am familiar with, although the latter is not yet proven in Robinson's book.

The kind of answer I'm hoping for is a full solution. This is a big ask, so I'll be happy with strong hints or perhaps something like a list of bullet points of intermediate steps.

---

Please help  :)

Comment: I think this is easier than you think. You know from Exercise 3.3.5 and the given coprimeness condition that ${\rm Aut_c}(G)$ is trivial. Now apply the Krull Remak Schmidt Theorem with $k=r$ and you find that the two decompositions are the same after reordering the factors.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt. One thing I don't understand is how the *no nontrivial abelian direct factors* part of that exercise satisfied. Please would you write up an answer?

Comment: An abelian direct factor would contradict the assumed coprimeness condition - think about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brief answer. We are told that $\gcd(|Z(G)|,|G_{\rm ab}|)=1$. But we know from Exercise 3.3.5 that $|{\rm Aut_c}(G)| = |{\rm Hom}(G_{\rm ab},Z(G))|$, so $|{\rm Aut_c}(G)|=1$.

Now, if $G$ has two Remak decompositions then we can apply the Krull Remak Schmidt Theorem with $k=r$, and the elements $\alpha \in {\rm Aut_c}(G)$ must be equal to the identity, so the two decompositions are the same after permuting the direct factors.

If one of the factors, say $H_1$ was nontrivial and abelian, then we would have $H_1 \le Z(G)$, but $G/(H_2 \times \cdots H_r) \cong H_1$, so $H_1$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of $G_{\rm ab}$, and hence $|H_1|$ divides $\gcd(|Z(G)|,|G_{\rm ab}|)=1$, contradiction.