# Let $G$ be a finite group. Then $G$ is completely reducible iff $G={\rm Soc}(G)$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups, direct-product, socle

This is **Exercise 3.3.10** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Socle%2C%20finite%20group%2C%20completely%20reducible&p=10), it is new to MSE, although the equivalence in question is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38039/104041).

### The Details:

Since definitions vary, on page 15, *ibid.*, paraphrased, it states that

> A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is *normal* in $G$ if one of the following equivalent statements is satisfied:
>
> (i) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (ii) $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (iii) $x^{-1}nx\in N$ for all $x\in G, n\in N$.

We call a group *simple* if $G\neq 1$ and $1$ and $G$ are the only normal subgroups of $G$. This definition is equivalent to the one found on page 16.

Robinson defines *completely reducible* in terms of $\Omega$-groups on page 85; however, for $\Omega=\varnothing$, the definition is equivalent to saying

> a group is *completely reducible* if it is a direct product of a possibly infinite family of simple groups.

The definition of the *socle* of $G$, which I denote as ${\rm Soc}(G)$, is on page 87:

> The subgroup generated by all minimal normal subgroups of a group $G$ is called the *socle*: should the group fail to have any minimal normal subgroups, [. . .] the socle of $G$ is defined to be $1$.

On the same page, we find

> the concept of a *minimal normal subgroup* of a group $G$, by which is understood a *nontrivial* normal subgroup that does not contain a smaller nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that $G$ is completely reducible if and only if it equals its socle.

### Thoughts:

I have only trivial things to add. However, it does not seem like a bunch of "iff"-statements starting with "$G$ is completely reducible" and ending with "$G={\rm Soc}(G)$" is easy to find. So I start out with,

"Suppose $G$ is completely reducible. Then $G$ is a direct product of a possibly infinite family of simple groups; it cannot be an infinite family since $G$ is finite."

Now what do I do next?

I'm guessing some form of the Krull-Remak-Schmidt Theorem (details of which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4174806/104041)) might be useful; I'm not sure why.

Once I'm done there, of course, the next task would be to show that $G={\rm Soc}(G)$ implies that $G$ is completely reducible.

I find [the following comment on the answer to a similar question (linked to above)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38025/finite-non-abelian-groups-such-that-socg-g?noredirect=1#comment83639_38039) useful conceptually:

> The [. . .] equivalence should be a little surprising since minimal normal subgroups need not be simple (just direct products of simples). However, for a minimal normal subgroup *not* to be simple, there has to be something above it to swirl its factors around. If $G={\rm Soc}(G)$, then there is nothing on top to do the mixing.

I'm hoping for a complete solution, although I would be more than content with a collection of strong hints.

This question appears to be one that I should be able to answer myself. I've given it a few days, though, and I've got little to show for it; I want to move on.

Please help  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is finite and completely reducible, then it’s a finite product of simple groups. Each one of these groups is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and together they generate $G$ so $G$ is its socle.

Assume that $G$ is its socle. Let $\mathcal{N}$ be a minimal set of minimal normal subgroups that generate $G$.

Let $S \subset \mathcal{N}$, and $N \in \mathcal{N} \backslash S$. Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the $N’ \in S$, then $H \triangleleft G,N \triangleleft G$, so the subgroup $K$ generated by $N$ and $H$ is exactly $HN$. Now, $H \cap N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $N$. So if it not trivial, $N \subset H$ and thus $\mathcal{N}$ could be replaced by $\mathcal{N} \backslash \{N\}$ – contradicting minimality.

In particular, it follows that (with the same notations) $|H|=\prod_{s \in S}{|s|}$.

Consider, for each $N \in \mathcal{N}$, the subgroup $H_N$ generated by the $N’ \in \mathcal{N} \backslash \{N\}$. By the above, $H_NN=G$, $H_N \cap N$ is trivial. We have a morphism $f: G \rightarrow P=\prod_N{G/H_N}$ between groups of same cardinality. But if $N \in \mathcal{N}$, and $x \in G$, then $x \in H_NN$ and thus the element $v \in P$ which is $x$ at $N$ and the neutral element everywhere else is in the image of $f$ (in $f(N)$, precisely).

Thus $f$ is surjective and hence an isomorphism. To conclude, it remains to show that $G/H_N$ is simple, ie that there is no normal subgroup $H_N < K < G$. Indeed, if there were one, then $K=H_N (K \cap N)$ and thus $K \cap N$ would be a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ properly contained in $N$ – a contradiction.